# Find First Non-zero Value in Each Row of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
                   [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 7.0, 0.0],
                   [0.0, 0.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0]
                  ]
                  , columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'])

     A    B     C     D     E     F     G     H
0  0.0  2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0
1  1.0  0.0   1.0   3.0   1.0   1.0   7.0   0.0
2  0.0  0.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0
```

And I'd like to return a **series** (not a list) of the first non-zero value in each row. This currently works but `lookup` returns a list instead of a series (I know I can convert the list to a series) but I'm assuming there's a better way:

```
first_nonzero_colnames = (df > 0).idxmax(axis=1, skipna=True)
df.lookup(first_nonzero_colnames.index, first_nonzero_colnames.values)

[  2.   1.  13.]
```

I can use `.apply` but I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
res = df[df != 0.0].bfill(axis=1)['A']
```

all i'm doing is replacing all non-zeros with `nan`s and then filling them in from the right, which forces all resulting values in the first column to be the first non-zero value in the row.

or, a quicker way, as suggested by @piRSquared:

```
df.replace(0, np.nan).bfill(1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Comment: Such a good answer.  I'm still working on mine.  but I'd `df.replace(0, np.nan).bfill(1).iloc[:, 0]`

Comment: @piRSquared: Yeah, I had something similar, `df.mask(df == 0).bfill(1).iloc[:,0]`, but was just barely beat!

Comment: just ran `%%timeit` my suggestion takes 3rd the time, but it's the same concept.  I don't mind you including it in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

@acushner's answer is better.  Just putting this out there.

use `idxmax` and `apply`

```
m = (df != 0).idxmax(1)
df.T.apply(lambda x: x[m[x.name]])

0     2.0
1     1.0
2    13.0
dtype: float64
```

This also works:

```
m = (df != 0).idxmax(1)
t = zip(m.index, m.values)

df.stack().loc[t].reset_index(1, drop=True)
```

Comment: Don't they have something in pandas for fancy indexing, so something like `df[np.arange(3),m]`? Or that won't make sense because that won't keep the `2D` format for dataframes?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work:

```
df[df!=0].cumsum(axis=1).min(axis=1)
Out[74]: 
0     2.0
1     1.0
2    13.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that I would call this "better". But it returns a series in a one liner.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[np.where(x > 0)[0][0]], axis=1)
>>>
0     2.0
1     1.0
2    13.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to avoid using `apply`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very fast way using .apply and [.nonzero()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nonzero.html)

```
 df2.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[x.nonzero()[0][0]], axis=1)
 >>>
 0     2.0
 1     1.0
 2    13.0
 dtype: float64
```

performance:

```
%%timeit
df2.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[x.nonzero()[0][0]], axis=1)
>>>
190 µs ± 8.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```